# Relay Buzzer Circuit

Tags: battery-charging, low-battery

I'm trying to set up a circuit to protect a battery in a battery box, using some parts I had lying around. Its job is to open the primary relay (load/charging) and sound a buzzer when the supply drops but I want to be able to turn off everything including the buzzer with the switch. The supply is the load end of a Victron MPPT controller, that I can configure to turn off when the voltage goes above the high value or below the low value. The primary relay is an automotive (WM686)100AMP mechanical relay and the second relay is a cheap Chinese (SRD-12VDC-SL-C) 10amp mechanical relay. The problem I am having is once the supply is dropped, I can't turn off the buzzer. Somehow it seems to be creating another circuit for the buzzer, I'm guessing through one of the relay coils, or the shutdown behaviour of the load circuit on the MPPT controller, I've tried putting diodes (HER306) on the positive end of all of the relay coils, the buzzer, and the MPPT load supply. Obviously I'm not an electrical engineer, just having some fun building something but perhaps there is something obvious I have overlooked?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

OK, well it appears as if the MPPT controller load + (bottom battery symbol), is going to ground when in disconnected mode. Any idea how I can prevent that from happening?

EDIT- Added Ground to the diagram. +12v is the battery symbol and 0v is the ground symbol according to the diagram app I'm using. Previous image the + was the long line side of the Battery Symbol and ground/0v was the short line side.

[image]

Comment: ground does not appear on your schematic.

Comment: You should edit the schematic so we know which is +12v and 0V.

Comment: I've added the + - (ground) to the schematic. I found the issue is that the + on the MPPT controller is going to ground when it disconnects to load.

Comment: For electrical safety reasons, it's generally wiser to cut the supply with a switch than cutting ground. For example what will you do when the relay contacts eventually break or weld?

Comment: The reason I am cutting ground is because I want to use a single switch for both circuits. I only want 1 switch as the master switch on the battery. The buzz should only activate when the switch is on but the power protection relay has disconnected, the switch would be silenced by turning off the master switch. I'm not sure how I would achieve this by switching on positive.